# API call with formData in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a React Native app where i'm sending an API request like this:

```js
let formData = new FormData();
    
let img = {
        name: 'Image.jpg',
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            uri: filePath,
      }

formData.append('file', JSON.stringify({img}));

let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
             Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
         },
        };

  const response = await fetch(apiUrl, options);
```

In postman when i send request like this it works:

[image]

But in app, the api request is not showing the result as expected. Am i missing something with the formData?

Comment: i believe you cannot send a file like you can do for string values.

Comment: You mean i can't add a file like this way?

Comment: On submit you dont need to do any operations for a file. make sure you keep updating the sate when you change file.

Comment: Are you using state or not? I have some references on react

Comment: I'm just not understanding why console formdata  shows blank {}.

Comment: You should be able to see FormData object on console.log.

Comment: You don't need to stringify img object.

Comment: Yaah i removed that but still FormData is consoling blank {} @ArafatZahan

Answer (score 0):

try it please.

```
formdata.append('file',{
    uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? photo.uri : 'file://' + photo.uri,
    name: 'test',
    type: 'image/jpeg' // or your mime type what you want
});
```

Comment: Tried it. But still when i console formdata it shows blank {} . Why is that happening? @İlker

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in

`const response = await fetch(apiUrl, options);`

You are using `await` to wait until the promise is resolved, so have you marked it's parent function as `async`?

Comment: Yes i did. That's not the problem.